# Case or coalesce in sqlalchemy to add new column to a query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a complex query with some custom models and i need to add column to this query.
This column must be a value of other column.
How can i do it in sqlalchemy query?

```sql
coalesce (
  (
    SELECT 
      indicator_table.count 
    FROM 
      indicator_table 
    WHERE 
      indicator_table.year = 2023 
      AND indicator_table.task_id = task_table_1.id
  ), 
  0
) as alias
```

`task_table` is joining after this with alias `task_table_1` so i need to use exactly this table.

This code

```sql
query = query.add_column(
  coalesce(
    session.query(Indicator.count).filter(Indicator.year == 2023).filter(Indicator.task_id == Task.id).as_scalar()
```

giving me next sql-expression:

```
coalesce (
  (
    SELECT 
      indicator_table.count 
    FROM 
      indicator_table, 
      task_table 
    WHERE 
      indicator_table.year = %(year_1) s 
      AND indicator_table.task_id = task_table.id
  ), 
  %(coalesce_2) s
) AS coalesce_1
```